# ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave events not working on chrome

Tags: angularjs, events

I have set up the following in my angular app

I have an image with the following ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave events tied to the image tag

```
<img ng-mouseover="infoIconStyle={'height':'50px','padding':'10px'}"  ng-mouseleave="infoIconStyle={'height':'0','padding':'0'}" src="images/info-icon.svg" />
```

These mouse over events are then sent to the following div

```
<div class="dataBoxInfoContent" ng-style="infoIconStyle">{{description}}</div>
```

Therefore when ng-mouseover is triggered the dataBoxInfoContent div opens due to the height going from 0 to 50px and when ng-mouseleave is triggered the div closes again.

However for some reason ng-mouseleave is not trigged when the mouse leaves the image and this is only in Google Chrome. All works fine in internet explorer and mozilla firefox.

Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: These types of issues are hard to isolate. Can you be 100% certain the mouse leave isn't firing? Are you basing that just off the fact that the style isn't changing? Have you considered setting `infoIconStyle` to a predefined set of classes rather than an inline style? Chrome may respond to that better. Build a couple classes that meet those styles and then on mouse over and leave do something like `infoIconStyle = "classname"`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is CSS issue, not Angular. If you can make a demo.. otherwise it's not possible to guess, because `ngMouseleave` of course works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I tried to pass class names and not inline css and still get the same issue but only in Chrome. All works fine in firefox and IE

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bpd27p1v/2/ - hmm seems to wrok in Chrome - check your code for typo.

Comment: This also worked for me earlier but I guess I must have changed something in my css to break this functionality in Chrome.

Comment: Guys this is pretty weird but I restarted my PC and this now works in Chrome...

Comment: In my case it just took restartarting Chrome. It had nothing to do with any extensions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Chrome and eventually tracked the issue down to a specific Chrome Extension (for me, it was the [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) extension).

If you have any javascript-profiling extensions, the slowness that those add to your page can sometimes cause unusual behavior in events (in particular, the mouse-movement events).

In the "Profiles" tab of the Chrome debugger, use the "Collect JavaScript CPU Profile" to find out which scripts, if any, are hogs, and then if you hover over the script on the right, it will tell you which chrome extension the hog is a part of.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will have a look at my JavaScript CPU Profile if this happens again. It's happened once or twice more which gets sorted out when I restart my  PC...

Comment: Thank you. Third time AngularJS Batarang has screwed me.

Comment: FWIW, [Batarang needs some love](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/194).

Comment: This solved my mysteries! (u know, the kind, I swear I didn't change anything, why did this stop working?) I just unchecked the "enable check-box" in Batarang and everything works as before :-)

Comment: As of now, I guess the golden rule is that is something is failing without a reason, check that Batarang is disabled, then test your angular app again