# How to create custom directives for mouseover and mouseleave in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create custom directives instead of ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave, since ng-mouseleave didnt work in chrome.

My requirement is when i mouseover, a popover should appear and when I mouseleave, it should close. The close functionality is not closing in few situations in chrome(the frequency of popover closing is inconsistent).

```
<div class="eleCalc" ng-mouseover="calcPopOver(i)" id="term{{i.Id}}" ng-mouseleave="hidePopOvers()">
                    {{calcNumbers(i)}}
</div>
```

calcPopOver function opens popup and 
hidePopOvers() closes.

Please help to create new directive.

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched for other people with this issue? I found this immediately, does it fix your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687002/ng-mouseover-and-ng-mouseleave-events-not-working-on-chrome

Comment: The issue might be something else because those two directives usually work in all common browsers. I would investiage the casue for this instead of implementing custom ones.

Comment: @BenHeymink Thanks for your reply. I know about this but it looks like client doesn't want to do settings in chrome. So I have to bring up new approach for the above. Can you help me?

Comment: @LordTribual This is something to do with settings in chrome. So, I am trying to build a new approach for the same functionality.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use custom directive like below to achieve the functionality you want.

```
app.directive('domDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
              element.on('click', function () {
                  element.html('You clicked me!');
              });
              element.on('mouseenter', function () {
                  element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
              });
              element.on('mouseleave', function () {
                  element.css('background-color', 'white');
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

The working code pen for same is as below.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbjQEm)

For more detail on custom directive like this visit below link.

[weblogs.asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want On mouseenter, i need to call calcPopover(i) function. which creates a popup with data.and On mouseleave, I need to call hidepopovers() to close the popovers.